# Write the contrapositive of "if $n$ is an even integer such that n + 1 is a square then n is divisible by 8"

Tags: propositional-calculus, formal-languages

For the purpose of clarity, I do not want anybody to prove this statement, I am just looking to get some help translating it into the contrapositive using *symbolic logic*. Right now I have the following translation:

---

Original Statement:

$$(\exists k \in \mathbb{Z} \quad n = 2k) \quad \land \quad (\exists m \in \mathbb{Z} \quad n+1 =m^2) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \text{n is divisible by 8}$$

Contrapositive Statement:

$$ \text{n is not divisible by 8} \quad \Rightarrow \quad (\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}  \quad n = 2k+1) \quad \lor \quad (\forall m \in \mathbb{Z}  \quad n+1 \neq m^2) $$

---

A couple of points of clarification:

- I wasn't sure how to write $n$ is divisible by 8. Perhaps it could have been stated as $\exists p \in \mathbb{Z} \quad n = 8p$?
- For the negation of $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z} \quad n = 2k$, I know that typically you might want to reverse the $\exists$ to an $\forall$, but I think what I wrote makes sense since the negation of even numbers is odd numbers.

Eventually I will try to prove this statement by contrapositive, but I want to get some practice in with translating mathematical statements into a more formal structure.

My question(s) are following:

1. Is the original translation correct? How might it be improved?
2. How could I more formally translate '$n$ is divisible by 8'?
3. Is the contrapositive stated correctly?

I also am not able to use $mod$ notation, $a|b$ notation, or anything that is unique to Abstract Algebra.

Comment: We usually write "$a$ is divisible by $b$' as $b\mid a$ so you could write this as $8\mid n$ and $8\not \mid n$.

Comment: @fleablood I don't have that notation at my disposal quite yet, so I just need to make sure I work within my boundaries. I think another way to say that "$a$ is divisible by $b$" would be to say that "$a$ is a multiple of $b$". Would you agree with that statement?

Comment: Using your language then just like "$n$ is even" is written as $\exist m: 2m = n$, how would you think "$n$ is divisible by $8$" should be written.  Doesn't "even" mean divisible by $2$?

Comment: That is like saying "*I can't use the word 'door' just yet.  I can only say 'passage through which one can go from one room to another or from the exterior to the interior'*"  It should not be a matter of changing the mathematics of what you are saying... it is merely a matter of using a more convenient abbreviation for the scenario.  It seems silly to refuse to use those notations... which are not even "*unique to Abstract Algebra*"

Comment: You are already using the phrase "$n$ is divisible by $8$"... The very meaning of $8\mid n$ *is* that $n$ is divisible by $8$.  They mean the same thing, they convey the same information.  They can even be read aloud in the same way.  The one does not use higher machinery or anything of the sort.

Comment: @JMoravitz On second thought, I think there's no real sense in my trying to make "n is divisible by 8" more complicated than $8 | n$. In my course, and in my current level of education, I haven't been introduced to $ a | b$ so I just wanted to work within those parameters and that entails using quantifiers. But It is not much of a stretch to just use that notation if that's how it is defined, so I don't think it will hurt to use that.

Answer (score 1):

"if $n$ is an even integer such that $n+1$ is square then n is divisible by 8"

The original statement can be written as:

$$ (\forall k \in \mathbb{Z} \quad [n = 2k \quad \land \quad n \neq2k+1]) \quad \land \quad (\exists m\in \mathbb{Z}\quad m^2 = n+1) \quad \Rightarrow \quad 8 |n $$

The contrapositive is then:

$$ 8 \nmid n \quad \Rightarrow \quad (\exists k\in \mathbb{Z} \quad [n \neq 2k \quad \lor \quad n = 2k+1]) \quad \lor \quad (\forall m \in \mathbb{Z} \quad m^2 \neq n +1) $$

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is not divisible by 8, then either $n$ is not an even integer or  $n+1$ is not a square.

Comment: I agree with that in a plain language sense, but I am trying to develop my skills in writing it out more formally.

Comment: There's nothing "more formal" about symbolic logic.  And there's nothing less formal about "plain language".  If you want help with symbolic logic *say* so.

Comment: @fleablood I have edited my question to include symbolic logic.